# How do I hide the "read ....save as" notification for an accdr file

Tags: security, ms-access, ms-access-2010

When I make the *accdb* file to an *accdr* file and open it with Access 2010, the database is created with Access 2010 and OpenGateSoftware’s UI builder. I get a notification bar at the top saying: *Read only ... save as*.

The meaning with me creating an *accdr* file is that it shall be Read only NOT how to get rid of it. Anyone knowing how to hide this Notification bar? The database is a catalogue for Air Mail collectors.